# Error freezing model in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used the retrain.py script to retrain the inception V3 model. From this script, I get several files: the output_graph.pb file., the labels.txt and the 3 checkpoint files (.meta,.data.index) using the writer_version= tf.train.SaverDef.V2. Following some ideas, I created my freezing script.

```
input_graph_name = "output_graph.pb"
output_graph_name = "frozen_graph.pb"
checkpoint_path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python 3.5.2\\tensorflow\\final\\output\\tmp\\map-0"
input_graph_path = os.path.join('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python 3.5.2\\tensorflow\\final\\output\\tmp', input_graph_name)
input_saver_def_path = ""
input_binary = True
output_node_names = "final_result"
restore_op_name = "save/restore_all"
filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"

freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path,
                          input_saver_def_path,
                          input_binary,
                          checkpoint_path,
                          output_node_names,
                          restore_op_name,
                          filename_tensor_name,
                          output_graph_path,
                          clear_devices,
                          "")
```

However, I am getting the error:

TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensors/Variables. Not a variable: Tensor("final_training_ops/biases/final_biases:0", shape=(2,), dtype=float32).

I know there is a node called final_training_ops/biases/final_biases:0 in the retrain.py but I only have interest on the final_result node which will be used to get the classification result. Some posts on the internet mention the .pbtxt + .ckpt files (using the  writer_version= tf.train.SaverDef.V1) to freeze the model, but my computer freezes. I hope someone can help me to figure out what to do.

Comment: I know this is not what you are doing, but, as an alternative, I generally prefer to get my frozen graph from the running session instead of from a checkpoint, which you can do with a function like [this](https://gist.github.com/javidcf/445d0578e9e749af5779880393e90853) (then you'd call [`tf.train.write_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/write_graph) to actually get the binary or text graph file).

Comment: @jdehesa thank you for your feedback. I would like to ge the frozen graph without exclude any possible way to do that. I will try your way.